# simple javascript for cms wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Hi guys i need simple javascript for wysiwyg for my cms to bold text, underline text, line-trought, put text to left, to right, to center and add quotes to selected text. I don't know how to do that because i don't know javascript. Can anybody please do that for me? My code is:

```
<form action="create_post.php">
        <input type="text" id="title_post" placeholder="Enter your post name" name="title_post">
        <div id="toolbox">
        <a href="#" id="bold">icon</a>
        <a href="#" id="italic">icon</a>
        <a href="#" id="underline">icon</a>
        <a href="#" id="line-through">icon</a>
        <a href="#" id="left_text">icon</a>
        <a href="#" id="center_text">icon</a>
        <a href="#" id="right_text">icon</a>
        <a href="#" id="quotes">icon</a>
        </div>
        <textarea id="content_post" name="content_post"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Create post"> 
        </form>
```

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/ -- Take a look at the quick install on the home-page.

Comment: a list - http://designhuntr.com/jquery-text-editor-plugins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for a text editor I use this tool [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the **[Bootstrap-Wysiwyg](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/)** plugin.

> This tiny (5KB, < 200 lines) jQuery Bootstrap plugin turns any DIV into a WYSIWYG rich-content editor, inspired by CLEditor and bootstrap-wysihtml5.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend utilising an existing editor such as CKEditor, TinyMCE or Bootstrap WYSIWYG (as vdenotaris pointed out). These editors can can be customised to function exactly how you want, and will also include lots of extra features that you may need in the long run.

If you still want to build your own, try investigating the `contenteditable` attribute.

It works like this

```
<div contenteditable="true">Editable content<div>
```

See http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/ for more information.

Now your content is editable, you will then need to make your buttons alter the text using some JavaScript. I would suggest you learn the basics (finding elements, setting styles, event handlers etc) before attempting a more advanced system such as this.

Hopefully that helps!

Edit:

I found a tutorial that describes exactly what you are trying to do:

https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1096/using_the_html5_attribute_contenteditable_to_create_a_wysiwyg#part3